# Understanding toggle in hover

Tags: jquery

I found this code snippet that allowed me to fadeTo a certain value depending on whether the ID in question was being hovered over or not. However I am having trouble understanding part of the code snippet in question and would like clarification please.

This is the code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#food-roulette").hover(function () {   
        this.toggle = !this.toggle;      
        $("#food-roulette").stop().fadeTo(100, this.toggle ? 0.4 : 1);
    });
});   
});
```

I have two questions.

1)What is toggle? Is this a boolean variable in the JQuery library? How is it intended to be used.

2) `this.toggle = !this.toggle`. This line is confusing the hell out of me. Under my assumption, toggle is initially true, and as soon as I hover over the button, toggle is set to false, so by the ternary operation the button opacity should be 1, but it is instead 0.4. So in a sense it's working in reverse. If i put the `this.toggle = !this.toggle` line after the `$("#food-roulette").stop().fadeTo(100, this.toggle ? 0.4 : 1);`, then it works in reverse where the button is faded until i hover over it.

So can someone explain to me the logic in those lines and why it works the way it does. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: In jQuery `toggle()` is a method. It will reverse states like like an on/off light switch. `this.toggle` looks like a property ...no parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.toggle is an undefined variable in the context of this. As soon as this.toggle = !this.toggle is called, it's basically saying: undefined = !undefined, which results in true. The first time this hover is called, it'd therefore fade to 0.4

You can check this yourself by opening the Chrome developer tools (f12), viewing the console, and then at the > prompt type in this.toggle - you'll see undefined. After typing this.toggle = !this.toggle you'll see true.

[image]

Comment: Ok that makes sense, appreciate the explanation. Any idea what the toggle variable in general is used for in the JQuery library (I assume for methods that are toggle related, but maybe more to it?)

Comment: There's a toggle() function in jQuery which hides and shows elements, but in the example above it's just being used as a random variable name. You could change it to this.banana and it would do the same thing.

Comment: Another question just occurred, this may be because of how Javascript works but initially toggle is undefined, so is it then automatically set to false? Or is undefined read as false in Javascript?

Comment: No, it'll be undefined. Although undefined will result in false for a few things, if you tried:
    if(this.toggle == false) {
        // this would not be executed    
    }

because this.toggle == undefined

Comment: ok thanks again, guess this is one of those few things where it will be false :)